# How to run a php or html file in default inside a folder?

Tags: php, html, web

This might be a very basic question. I have a folder in my website and inside that there is couple of php and html files which are connected to each other. This is the path:

```
http://107.170.253.5/login
```

First question is I don't want the user see this path. And second question is I want the user when click on above link. It goes directly into the login.html.
Any help or reference will be appreciated.

Comment: like this http://107.170.253.5/login/login.html ?

Comment: try expaining as "I want this url to point at this file" - if that's not what you mean, that should also indicate the question is hard to understand as written (be more explicit in your expectations).

Comment: @unknown That was the answer. Now I do not want anyone to see  107.170.253.5/login/

Comment: Use .htaccess redirect rules, is the simplest way out of your problem

Comment: @VovaLando and probably entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a .htacess file and add these

```
//only for login dir so that no one sees any file inside it.

<Directory your_full_dir_name/login/>
Options -Indexes
</Directory>

//for whole website so that no one sees any file inside it.

<Directory root_dir_name>
Options -Indexes
</Directory>

//to make login.html default page

DirectoryIndex login.html
```

Comment: I doubt login.html is desired as the index file for the whole doc root (it should be in the relevant directory section); "so that no one sees any file inside it" is quite misleading - all it does is prevent file listings for folders _if the directory index doesn't exist_ - you don't need `-Indexes` for the question as asked.

Comment: you can add index.html or any other file you want too to the Directory Index

Comment: @unknown What should I write inside index.html file?

Comment: that comment was for @AD7six

Comment: you have to just add the .htaccess file

Comment: @unknown I know how to configure apache =) - other readers won't understand why you're adding login.html as a directory index for the whole site - you don't need to, put it in the relevant directory block.

Comment: I am trying to make .htacess but it is saving as .htacess.txt. I think something is wrong!

Comment: @AD7six ok let's change it only to the login folder then is it ok for you ?

Comment: @Bernard are you using windows ?

Comment: no I am using mac. I just added an index file which is empty and as you can see there is nothing to show. Now is there any way to show login.html instead of nothing?

Comment: I just wanted to avoid security whole

Comment: No I want the user click on  107.170.253.5/login direct them to  107.170.253.5/login/login

Comment: why do you want to display the login twice i think that is a bad idea

Comment: Yes you are right.For your main answer about .htaccess, what is root_dir_name?

Comment: the main folder where index.html is placed (It works !) file on your server